# Short URL for twitter tweet

Tags: javascript

Twitter button Final code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 40px;"class="twitter-share-button" data-url=" <?php echo $short_url;?>"  " data-text="Check this out!">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

the mention above code only i used.In using php tag it is work in while highlighting twitter button the link should be shown like shorturl name.But it doesn't seems to be tweet for twitter.

How to fix this?